# How to view meshes at a lower quality to prevent lag

Tags: mesh

Often I am trying to work with a scene that has many high-quality and high poly count meshes. I do not have a very beefy computer so often it lags and crashes when I am trying to edit them, duplicate them, etc. Is there a way to view high-quality meshes at a lower quality? I need it to be low quality enough so that my computer can handle it but also not so low quality so that I can barely recognize it.

Comment: I've not tried this method, but I know that Decimate Modifier reduces the polygon count of the mesh. So try using that modifier but only for viewport and not for render. Or if you have subsurfs on the meshes, Simplify option (under Scene Properties)can help you.

Comment: I guess there are several ways to simplify your scene but it really depends on the objects, the scene, how you need to use it, etc... please give some examples